# CakePHP/mysql: select found_rows can't run in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm using CakePHP and trying to retrieve FOUND_ROWS() for a query that runs several times in a loop (each time with a different WHERE section). The strangest thing is happening: it returns the correct result for the first query - and then the same exact result for subsequent queries.

This is the code:

```
$article = new Article();
    $query = $db->buildStatement(
        array(
        'table' => $db->fullTableName($article)
        , 'alias' => 'Article'
        , 'order' => '`Article`.`publish_date` desc'
        , 'offset' => $startIndex
        , 'joins' => array(
                        array(
                            'table' => 'articles_categories',
                            'alias' => 'ArticlesCategories',
                            'type' => 'inner',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                'ArticlesCategories.article_id = Article.id',
                            ),
                        )
                        )
        , 'limit' => $this->maxNumArticlesToLoadPerPage
        , 'conditions' => "ArticlesCategories.category_id = $categoryId and publish_date <= now()"
        , 'fields' => array('Article.id', 'Article.name', 'Article.search_engine_teaser', 'Article.image_file_name', 'Article.content_modified', 'ArticlesCategories.category_id')),
    $article
    );

    $query = str_replace('SELECT', 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', $query);
    $articles = $article->query($query);

    // also return how many total articles are in this category
    $numArticlesInCategory = $article->query('select found_rows()')[0][0]['found_rows()'];
```

Now, where real curiosity here is that I used `ET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'` in the mysql database to track down what's going on, and it appears that the first query is indeed run several times in a loop, but the query `select found_rows()` is only run once!

I also tried to run `select SQL_NO_CACHE found_rows()`, but that didn't help.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your models `$cacheQueries` property setting, it might be `true`, causing the query to be cached on the CakePHP side. Use the second `query()` parameter to disable caching per query:

```
query('sql', false)
```

Btw., `ArticlesCategories.category_id = $categoryId` looks like a possible SQL injection vulnerability, you should never insert data in queries that way, *always* use the `key => value` syntax for conditions, or use prepared statements!

Also model classes shouldn't be instantiated directly, instead `ClassRegistry::init()` should be used.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Retrieving Your Data > Model::query()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Model Attributes > cacheQueries](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#cachequeries)**

Comment: THANK YOU. query('sql', false) did the trick. And thank for the other tips as well!